# How to pass a parameter in a CakePHP redirect to an external URL

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to pass a parameter to an external URL through a CakePHP(2) redirect, but I can't find any documentation on how to get it done. In this case I'm trying to pass the value of :param into the target URL.

```
Router::redirect('/:param/contact', 'http://www.otherdomain.com/:param/contact', array('status' => 301));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not using htaccess directly? How dynamic is that :param param?

Comment: I thought of that, however it depends on the result of some earlier PHP rules so I can't do this through htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

If there is earlier PHP involed, what's wrong with

```
Router::redirect(
    '/' . $param . '/contact', 'http://www.otherdomain.com/' . $param . '/contact',
    array('status' => 301));
```

Comment: The earlier PHP code is run in external RouteClasses. These only return true/false after which this redirect rule should be run. In other words, I don't know the value of :param.

Comment: Can you update your question with more details around how that param is generated/used?